# check_smtp not working when scheduled

Tags: smtp, nagios

I am trying to set up a new check in Nagios 3.5.0, making sure that my mail server is contactable on port 25 over the internet.

I am using the check_smtp command. When I run this command from the command line I get this:

```
[root@cwp-nagios-03 libexec]# ./check_smtp -H mail.****.com
SMTP OK - 0.068 sec. response time|time=0.068033s;;;0.000000
```

This looks like everything working correctly, so I added a new service definition:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               CL_WEB_CHECKS_DR
    service_description     Mail Server
    check_command           check_smtp!mail.***.com
}
```

When this command is run by Nagios, I get the following result instead:

```
Status Information: Connection refused
SMTP CRITICAL - 0.001 sec. response time
Performance Data:   time=0.001362s;;;0.000000
```

I am a bit lost as to why this is happening, so any help would be great!

Also, I am sure you will want to see it, so here is the command definition for check_smtp:

```
# 'check_smtp' command definition
define command{
    command_name    check_smtp
    command_line    $USER1$/check_smtp -H $HOSTADDRESS$
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mismatch between your command definition and your service definition.

To resolve, do **either** of the following. Not both.

1. In your command, try changing `$HOSTADDRESS$` to `$ARG1$`.
2. In your service definition, take out the exclamation point and everything after it, and then ensure that you are actually setting a correct `host_address` for your host.

Comment: Ah! Im an idiot!

The check is running on a fake host (localhost) and I totally forgot about this! Too much time banging my head against the wall!